# Font size of TextView in Android application changes on changing font size from native settings

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-fonts

I want to specify my own text size in my application, but I am having a problem doing this.

When I change the font size in the device settings, the font size of my application `TextView` also changes.

Comment: it is default behavior that if you change the font size of your device native font then it also effect to your application font size.

Comment: you can find answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706076/font-size-and-images-for-different-devices/16910589#16910589

Comment: Use sp for text size…because but it is scaled by the user’s font size preference. Use dp for everything else.

Answer (score 285, accepted):

Actually, Settings font size affects only sizes in `sp`. So all You need to do - define `textSize` in `dp` instead of `sp`, then settings won't change text size in Your app.

Here's a link to the documentation: [Dimensions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)

However please note that the expected behavior is that the fonts in all apps respect the user's preferences. There are many reasons a user might want to adjust the font sizes and some of them might even be medical - visually impaired users. Using `dp` instead of `sp` for text might lead to unwillingly discriminating against some of your app's users.

i.e:

```
android:textSize="32dp"
```

Comment: A long while back I wanted to know if there were any rule for when I should use `sp` and when I should use `dp`. I got a really good response here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638691/android-sp-vs-dp-texts-what-would-adjust-the-scale-and-what-is-the-philosoph

Answer (score 135):

The easiest to do so is simply to use something like the following:

```
android:textSize="32sp"
```

If you'd like to know more about the `textSize` property, you can check the [Android developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3atextSize).

Comment: this is actually why the TS has the issue, using 'sp' instead of 'dp'

Comment: I still don't know why there are 100 upvotes. because if we use sp for set textsize in application. Then we change the font size in Setting, the TextView in application also change

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: You should use dp if you want your text to remain the same across different screen sizes

Answer (score 56):

Use the `dimension` type of resources like you use `string` resources ([DOCS](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)).

In your `dimens.xml` file, declare your dimension variables:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <dimen name="textview_height">25dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="textview_width">150dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="ball_radius">30dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="font_size">16sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Then you can use these values like this:

```
<TextView
   android:layout_height="@dimen/textview_height"
   android:layout_width="@dimen/textview_width"
   android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"/>
```

You can declare different `dimens.xml` files for different types of screens.
Doing this will guarantee the desired look of your app on different devices.

When you don't specify `android:textSize` the system uses the default values.

Comment: issue is not screens. It is the native font size selected in android display settings which leads to the issue mentioned

Answer (score 29):

Also note that if the textSize is set in code, calling `textView.setTextSize(X)` interprets the number (X) as SP. Use `setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, X)` to set values in **dp**.

Answer (score 16):

It is not a good thing to have to specify DIP or SP again by code when already defined in a dimen.xml file.

I think that the best option is to use PX when using a dimen.xml value :

```
tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.txt_size));
```

This way, you can switch from DP to SP if needed in dimen.xml file without having to change any code.

Answer (score 12):

simple way to prevent the whole app from getting effected by system font size is to updateConfiguration using a base activity.

```
//in base activity add this code.
public  void adjustFontScale( Configuration configuration) {

    configuration.fontScale = (float) 1.0;
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    metrics.scaledDensity = configuration.fontScale * metrics.density;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    adjustFontScale( getResources().getConfiguration());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use this code:

```
android:textSize="32dp"
```

it solves your problem but you must know that you should respect user decisions.
by this, changing text size from device settings will not change this value. so that's why you need to use **sp** instead of **dp**.
So my suggestion is to review your app with different system font sizes(small,normal,big,...)

https://stacklearn.ir

Answer (score 4):

this solutions is with Kotlin and without using the deprecated function resources.updateConfiguration

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        adjustFontScale(resources.configuration)
    }

    private fun adjustFontScale(configuration: Configuration?) {
        configuration?.let {
            it.fontScale = 1.0F
            val metrics: DisplayMetrics = resources.displayMetrics
            val wm: WindowManager = getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
            wm.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(metrics)
            metrics.scaledDensity = configuration.fontScale * metrics.density

            baseContext.applicationContext.createConfigurationContext(it)
            baseContext.resources.displayMetrics.setTo(metrics)

        }
    }
```

Observation: this is the same solution as the [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49710354/2091181) but udpated with Kotlin

Answer (score 1):

this may help. add the code in your custom Application or BaseActivity

```
/**
 * 重写 getResource 方法，防止系统字体影响
 *
 * @return
 */
@Override
public Resources getResources() {
    Resources resources = super.getResources();
    if (resources != null && resources.getConfiguration().fontScale != 1) {
        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.fontScale = 1;
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
    }
    return resources;
}
```

however, Resource#updateConfiguration is deplicated in API level 25, which means it will be unsupported some day in the future.

Answer (score 1):

for kotlin, it works for me

```
priceTextView.textSize = 12f
```

Answer (score 1):

change the DP to sp it is good pratice for android
android:textSize="18sp"

Answer (score 1):

in android 8 this solution work for me

add this code in base activity

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
    final Configuration override = new Configuration(newBase.getResources().getConfiguration());
    override.fontScale = 1.0f;
    applyOverrideConfiguration(override);
}
```

source
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57225687/7985871

Answer (score 0):

If units used are SP, not DP, and you want to override system font scaling, all you do is override one method in activity - [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546805/how-to-prevent-system-font-size-changing-effects-to-android-application/53970324#53970324).

*resources.updateConfiguration* is deprecated and buggy (on Oreo I had issues with formatted text).

Answer (score 0):

Override `getResources()` in Activity.

Set TextView's size in sp as usual like `android:textSize="32sp"`

```
override fun getResources(): Resources {
    return super.getResources().apply {
        configuration.fontScale = 1F
        updateConfiguration(configuration, displayMetrics)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually change size from dimen in resources file

```html
<resources>
    <dimen name="siez_1">40px</dimen>
    <dimen name="siez_2">50px</dimen>
    <dimen name="siez_3">60px</dimen>

</resources>
```