# How to make font sizes in app to not get effected by changing Settings Font size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have my app running well as per design when the font size is at "Normal" on Settings->Display->FontSize.

When i change the font size to Small/Large entire content is mashed up. My app is content intensive and this is badly effecting the app.

Lets say, action bar title is like "Privacy and Settings". The title runs off the bounds/ellipsizes when font size is set to "Large" in System Settings. The listview contents look pathetic.

Is there a way to make sure that the change in Settings->Fonts doesn't effect our app?

Flipboard app does that.

Comment: You do realize that the exact users who up their default font size are the people who cannot read the smaller print and therefore have changed it on purpose?

Comment: Yes i do agree that the settings is for users benefit. But thats the requirement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally got the solution.
Google strictly recommends to use "sp" for fonts. However, if you do not want the text to be scaled based on user font settings, use "dp". The font size will not change in a given device if you go to settings->fonts. Your UI will remain just like you designed it for.

Thanks Aswin for your inputs. And thanks to Joseph Earl for answering question at [Android sp vs dp texts - what would adjust the 'scale' and what is the philosophy of support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638691/android-sp-vs-dp-texts-what-would-adjust-the-scale-and-philosophy-of-support)

Comment: The font size would still change if the user changes their display scale, which changes the scale of dp.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56780065/1089841 This link might help

Answer (score 2):

It is best to follow what Google recommends i.e to use 'sp' instead of 'dp'. Here is an updated solution which helped me - [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49710354/9623984)

```
 //in base activity add this code.
public  void adjustFontScale( Configuration configuration) {

    configuration.fontScale = (float) 1.0;
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    metrics.scaledDensity = configuration.fontScale * metrics.density;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    adjustFontScale( getResources().getConfiguration());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use dp or dip instead of sp in textSize

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you can do it but I don't recommend it.

```
float scale = getResources().getConfiguration().fontScale;
// This scale tells you what the font is scaled to.
// So if you want size 16, then set the size as 16/scale
float sizeNeeded = 16.0;
textView.setTextSize(sizeNeeded/scale);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I read it like, I should customize Textview and override setTextSize and add this scaling calculation there. Use this for all the textviews used in the application.