# android - prevent text size change on device text size

Tags: android, textview

I set font size 14sp for my textview in android , the problem is , when I change my phone text size , in the application it changes the size either , How can I prevent this ? How can I force text view to use the defined text size ?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21545906/how-to-make-font-sizes-in-app-to-not-get-effected-by-changing-settings-font-size

Answer (score 5):

When you declare a font with a size measured in sp ("scaled pixels") that measurement is supposed to be affected by the device font settings.  That's fully expected.

If you want a font size that never changes with the font settings, use dp measurements instead.