# Change Text Style of data from firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to change the text style of the data retrieved from the firebase database. It currently displays like this: [r][1]

![https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3Sfl.png] [1]

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_user_profile, container, false);

    btEdit = v.findViewById(R.id.button_edit);
    btRefresh = v.findViewById(R.id.button_refresh);
    mChildValueTextView = v.findViewById(R.id.childValueTextView);
    String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(uid);
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String age = dataSnapshot.child("age").getValue(String.class);
            String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            String sex = dataSnapshot.child("sex").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", name + ", " + sex + ", " + age);
            String childValue = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());
            mChildValueTextView.setText(childValue);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
        }
    };
    uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

'''

XML code

```
  <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/childValueTextView"/>
```

Comment: What do you mean through "I want to change the text style"? What exactly do you want to change? Provide us an example.

Comment: In the photo that I uploaded to this post, the data that is retrieved is in a font style that is pretty basic. I would like to change the font style that is displayed

Comment: What particular style do you want to use?

Comment: Any thing from Times new roman or just a better display text than what is show, but the most important is the size I need to display bigger

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264794/font-size-of-textview-in-android-application-changes-on-changing-font-size-from) out.

Comment: This helped me figure exactly what I needed, thank you Alex

Comment: Good to hear that Carlos ;)