# How to change the font size of an textview element in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am trying to display 2 items in a TextView. Is their any way to change the font of the single item in a TextView?

Here is the XML which I am using

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/Rowtext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:text="Listiems"
        android:background="@drawable/customshape"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Which way do you want to do this. On run time or in XML?

Comment: See this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/2179039/361230 and this - http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/177

Comment: @Fahad i have no idea which way s better, so u specify which way is better to do

Answer (score 17):

Use android:textSize.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:textColor="#88ffff00"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Time: 60"/>
```

Use sp if the user can rescale the text without breaking the UI. If rescaling the text would break the UI, use dp.

Comment: Isn't that we need to use SP for font sizes? I think it should be 40sp not 40dp

Comment: Use sp if the user can rescale the text without breaking the UI. If rescaling the text would break the UI, use dp. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11638914/2713250

Answer (score 8):

One way is to use TextView.setText() method and feed it with HTML, like this:

```
import android.text.Html;

String n = "<b>bold</b> <small>small</small>";
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(...)
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(n));
```

I often use it for some minor markup (like make part bolder or smaller)

Comment: erm, question was about changing font :-/
Shade's answer looks good!

Comment: There is a typo in "fromHtml" method. It says formHtml instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use the HTML class from this link http://code.google.com/p/android-richtexteditor/source/browse/trunk/src/net/sgoliver/Html.java?r=4 . We would be able to set font size from this class. Normal android.text.Html actually ignores font size. Tried and tested and it worked for me.

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);

String s = "<p>Some Text here<br><b>hi </b><font size =\"20\"><b><i>\"italics</i></b></font><b><i> </i></b><b><i><u>underline</u></i></b></p>";

tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add line in Text View Tag In XML:

```
android:textSize="32sp"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use html for this like this:

```
mytextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p> <font size="20" color="#0066FF" style="font-style:italic">Push this button</font> to start a new game.</p>"))
```

remove color and style attributes if you don't need them.

Comment: this is not working!!

Comment: @MohamadGhaithAlzin  9 years old answer... I checked it still works.

Comment: No, it generates an error from the redundant double quotation. However, I've tested it with `mytextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p> <font size=\"40\" color=#0066FF style=\"font-style:italic\">Push this button</font> to start a new game.</p>"));` It changes only the color but not for the size and italic!