# Using Button To Change TextView Size

Tags: java, android

I'm new to this but I have some understanding.
Currently I have an app that consists of lots of TextViews with a specific size , however i want to be able to implement a Button able change the TextView size of a TextView or all TextViews.
Can I have some help please with this with examples of codes (I prefer java)
Thank You!

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Asking for code without at least showing what you have tried so far to solve your problem such as your code example, links to other answers that are similar, or other such evidence of research effort on your part is unacceptable. Please at least post what you have so far. [Please see the help section about how to ask questions properly](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524221/change-the-font-size-of-an-textview-element-in-android

Answer (score 0):

On click of button you can change layout params of the textview you want to resize as following:

```
TextView tv=<find>
LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) tv.getLayoutParams();
lp2.height = 100;
tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
tv.requestLayout();
```