# How to set this text to the left of image in relative layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

[image: Snap]

```
            <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/row1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/main_row" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/alarm_clock"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="7:15 AM"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="35dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/alarm_clock"
                android:layout_below="@+id/alarm_clock"
                android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                android:text="Next Alarm"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="29dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/next_alarm_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/alarm_clock"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                android:text="Thursday 27th July"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="19dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/next_alarm_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/alarm_clock"
                android:layout_below="@+id/next_alarm_date"
                android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                android:text="8:05 AM"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="27sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/next_alarm_time_left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/alarm_clock"
                android:layout_below="@+id/next_alarm_time"
                android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                android:text="In 5 hrs 15 mins"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/add_alarm_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/next_alarm_time_left"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/add_alarm_icon"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:text="Add Alarm"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="13dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/add_alarm_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/add_alarm_text"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/alarm_clock"
                android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
                android:src="@drawable/add_alarm" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

The time 8:05 AM below day and date, goes beyond clock icon in some mobile due to screen size. how can i do that whenever the text touches clock icon remaining text(time) goes in a new line.

Thank you :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11638914/2382964 this can help you in solving your problem .

Answer (score 0):

Well i did it by my own :p

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/row1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/main_row" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/alarm_clock"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="7:15 AM"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="35dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/alarm_clock"
                android:layout_below="@id/alarm_clock"
                android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                android:text="Next Alarm"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="29dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/next_alarm_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/alarm_clock"
                android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                android:text="Thursday 27th July"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="19dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/next_alarm_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/alarm_clock"
                android:layout_below="@id/next_alarm_date"
                android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/add_alarm_icon"
                android:text="8:05 AM"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="27sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/next_alarm_time_left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/alarm_clock"
                android:layout_below="@id/next_alarm_time"
                android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                android:text="In 5 hrs 15 mins"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/add_alarm_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/add_alarm_text"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/alarm_clock"
                android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
                android:src="@drawable/add_alarm" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/add_alarm_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/next_alarm_time_left"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/add_alarm_icon"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:text="Add Alarm"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="13dp" />


        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make some improvements in your layout, like create a color.xml to set colors, string.xml to set the texts used on the app and instead using dp for textSize, use sp.

Check some good practices to build user interface here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html

Color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

String.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

   <string name="next_alarm_time_left">In 5 hrs 15 mins</string>
   <string name="add_alarm_text">Add Alarm</string>
   <string name="next_alarm_time">8:05 AM</string>
   <string name="next_alarm_date">Thursday 27th July</string>
   <string name="textView2">Next Alarm</string>
   <string name="alarm_clock">7:15 AM</string>

</resources>
```

The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/row1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

  <TextView
   android:id="@+id/alarm_clock"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:text="@string/alarm_clock"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
   android:textSize="35sp" />

  <TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView2"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/alarm_clock"
   android:layout_below="@+id/alarm_clock"
   android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
   android:text="@string/textView2"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
   android:textSize="29sp" />

  <TextView
   android:id="@+id/next_alarm_date"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/alarm_clock"
   android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
   android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
   android:text="@string/next_alarm_date"
   android:textColor="@color/white"
   android:textSize="19sp" />

  <TextView
   android:id="@+id/next_alarm_time"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/alarm_clock"
   android:layout_below="@+id/next_alarm_date"
   android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
   android:text="@string/next_alarm_time"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
   android:textSize="27sp" />

  <TextView
   android:id="@+id/next_alarm_time_left"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/alarm_clock"
   android:layout_below="@+id/next_alarm_time"
   android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
   android:text="@string/next_alarm_time_left"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
   android:textSize="20sp" />

  <TextView
   android:id="@+id/add_alarm_text"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/next_alarm_time_left"
   android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/add_alarm_icon"
   android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
   android:text="@string/add_alarm_text"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
   android:textSize="13sp" />

  <ImageView
   android:id="@+id/add_alarm_icon"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_above="@+id/add_alarm_text"
   android:layout_alignRight="@+id/alarm_clock"
   android:layout_marginRight="17dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you :) i will improve it ;)