# Android app UI messed up when I change from appearance from settings

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, fonts, dimensions

I have defined font size in android application, it works perfectly in all screen sizes, but when I change font size (appearance small, medium, large or x-large) from android phone settings, the UI is messed up with respect to font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use dp for setting the size of Text, it will sort your problem.

You should also refer this SO for when to using SP and DP.

[Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638691/android-sp-vs-dp-texts-what-would-adjust-the-scale-and-what-is-the-philosoph)

Comment: Thanks [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638691/android-sp-vs-dp-texts-what-would-adjust-the-scale-and-what-is-the-philosoph) **link** helped me

Comment: It's my pleasure. Happy to know to that it helped.